# 403 permission denied on Google Cloud Datastore .NET client API

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-datastore

Using the new Google Cloud Datastore v1beta client library, I am getting

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "message": "Unauthorized."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Unauthorized."
 }
}
```

for any request.  I created an app engine app, added the Cloud Datastore API, configured a service account, and I'm using it to authenticate my requests.

```
[TestMethod]
public void BasicBlindWrite()
{
    var service = new DatastoreService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { Authenticator = CreateAuthenticator() });

    var request = new GoogleData.BlindWriteRequest();
    var entity = new GoogleData.Entity();
    entity.Key = new GoogleData.Key();
    entity.Key.Path = new List<KeyPathElement>();
    entity.Key.Path.Add(new GoogleData.KeyPathElement { Kind = "Consumer", Name = "Consumer-1" });
    var firstName = new GoogleData.Property();
    firstName.Values = new List<GoogleData.Value>();
    firstName.Values.Add(new GoogleData.Value { StringValue = "Samuel"});
    entity.Properties = new GoogleData.Entity.PropertiesData();
    entity.Properties.Add("FirstName", firstName);
    request.Mutation = new GoogleData.Mutation();
    request.Mutation.Upsert = new List<GoogleData.Entity>();
    request.Mutation.Upsert.Add(entity);

    var response = service.Datasets.BlindWrite(request, "my-appengine-project-id").Fetch();
}

private OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient> CreateAuthenticator()
{
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(TestClientCredentials.ClientCertificateFilePath, "notasecret",
        X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

    var provider = new AssertionFlowClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, certificate)
    {
        ServiceAccountId = TestClientCredentials.CertificateEmailAddress,
        Scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore"
    };

    var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(provider, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);

    return authenticator;
}
```

If I use the web API console, it works.

** UPDATE **

Here's how I created the service account:

1. Created AppEngine application.
2. Navigated to Google APIs console.
3. Enabled Google Cloud Datastore API for AppEngine application.
4. Clicked "Create an OAuth 2.0 client ID..."
5. Gave it a dummy name.
6. Selected "Service Account" as Application Type.
7. Clicked "Create client ID".
8. Clicked "Download private key" (location represented as TestClientCredentials.ClientCertificateFilePath in code below).

Comment: I think it is the same issue I have? Can you compare your token with mine? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094641/google-datastore-token-not-authorized)

Comment: can you detail how you created the service account?

Comment: @proppy see update above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same answer as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17219683/656408).

In order for service account to be properly configured with your Cloud Datastore instance you have to create them using the [Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console) as described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#google_cloud_datastore_from_other_platforms).

Alternatively if you really want to use the service account you created using the [Google APIs console][3], you can do the following:

- Go to [cloud.google.com/console](https://cloud.google.com/console)
- Click on your *project id*
- Click on ⚙
- Click on *Teams*
- Click *Add member*
- Add your service account as a *Viewer*

Comment: This did not fix it, as creating a Service Account actually adds that email address to the Team Members automatically.  However, I tracked down this chat [http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32113/discussion-between-proppy-and-gert-cuykens] between you and the author in the other post, and disabling and re-enabling the Cloud Datastore API fixed the problem for me too.