# google datastore token not authorized?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

```
jwt1=`echo -n '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}' | openssl base64 -e`

jwt2=`echo -n '{\
"iss":"...@developer.gserviceaccount.com",\
"scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore",\
"aud":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",\
"exp":'$(($(date +%s)+3600))',\
"iat":'$(date +%s)'}' | openssl base64 -e`

jwt3=`echo -n "$jwt1.$jwt2" | tr -d '\n' | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-'`

jwt4=`echo -n "$jwt3" | openssl sha -sha256 -sign google.p12 | openssl base64 -e`

jwt5=`echo -n "$jwt4" | tr -d '\n' | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-'`

curl -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" -d \
"grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=$jwt3.$jwt5"
```

I receive a token successfully but when I use it I get permission denied?

When I copy the oauth2 token from https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta1/datasets/blindWrite#try-it
it works?

```
curl -X GET "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=$1"
curl -X GET "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token=$1"
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization:  Bearer $1" -X POST "https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta1/datasets/.../blindWrite" -d \
'{
 "mutation": {
  "upsert": [
   {
    "key": {
     "path": [
      {
       "kind": "person",
       "name": "gert"
      }
     ]
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}'
```

difference between the 2 tokens:

1) from jwt (permission denied)

```
{
 "issued_to": "522156758812-u8hj8dhnk5br3vnpqqvuscievhbnl0gg.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "audience": "522156758812-u8hj8dhnk5br3vnpqqvuscievhbnl0gg.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore",
 "expires_in": 3588,
 "email": "522156758812-u8hj8dhnk5br3vnpqqvuscievhbnl0gg@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
 "verified_email": true,
 "access_type": "offline"
}
{
 "email": "522156758812-u8hj8dhnk5br3vnpqqvuscievhbnl0gg@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
 "verified_email": true
}
```

2) from https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta1/datasets/blindWrite#try-it (works)

```
{
 "issued_to": "292824132082.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "audience": "292824132082.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "user_id": "116469479527388802962",
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
 "expires_in": 3568,
 "email": "gert.cuykens@gmail.com",
 "verified_email": true,
 "access_type": "online"
}
{
 "id": "116469479527388802962",
 "email": "gert.cuykens@gmail.com",
 "verified_email": true
}
```

What is wrong with my jwt received token?
How do I make jwt work also?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you detail how you created this service account `522156758812-u8hj8dhnk5br3vnpqqvuscievhbnl0gg@developer.gserviceaccount.com`

Comment: https://code.google.com/apis/console -> API Access -> create a other client id -> Service account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for service account to be properly configured with your Cloud Datastore instance you have to create them using the [Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console) as described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#google_cloud_datastore_from_other_platforms).

Alternatively if you really want to use the service account you created using the [Google APIs console][3], you can do the following:

- Go to [cloud.google.com/console](https://cloud.google.com/console)
- Click on your *project id*
- Click on APIs
- Make sure *Google Cloud Datastore API* is *ON*
- Click on the gear symbol (⚙) on the top right
- Click on *Teams*
- Click *Add member*
- Add your service account as a *Viewer*

Comment: a ok found it under the gear symbol

Comment: could it be the service is down right now, I get "503 Backend Error" on both tokens?

Comment: @GertCuykens what is your dataset id, and which service account are you using?

Comment: (added screenshot) gcl-11 using 522156758812-u8hj8dhnk5br3vnpqqvuscievhbnl0gg@developer.gserviceaccount.com or just gert.cuykens@gmail.com by using the api explorer, note that I tried to set it on "Can view" also.

Comment: The datastore API doesn't seems enabled for your project, I updated the instructions in my answer.

Comment: Can you make sure you turn it on from cloud.gooogle.com/console, not the Google APIs console

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32113/discussion-between-proppy-and-gert-cuykens)