# Error connecting to Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: c#, google-cloud-datastore

I tried to insert an Entity in Google Cloud DataStore, using .NET driver beta1. Here is the code:

```
String serviceAccountEmail = "***.apps.googleusercontent.com";

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(
    @"***-privatekey.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
   new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) {
       Scopes = new[] {
           Google.Apis.Datastore.v1beta1.DatastoreService.Scope.Datastore.ToString().ToLower()
       }
   }.FromCertificate(certificate));

// Create the service.
var service = new DatastoreService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "***",
});

var request = new GoogleData.BlindWriteRequest();
var entity = new GoogleData.Entity();
entity.Key = new GoogleData.Key();
entity.Key.Path = new List<KeyPathElement>();
entity.Key.Path.Add(new GoogleData.KeyPathElement { Kind = "KindTest", Name = "name" });
var firstName = new GoogleData.Property();
firstName.Values = new List<GoogleData.Value>();
firstName.Values.Add(new GoogleData.Value { StringValue = "FName" });
entity.Properties = new Dictionary<string, Property>();

entity.Properties.Add("FirstName", firstName);
request.Mutation = new GoogleData.Mutation();
request.Mutation.Upsert = new List<GoogleData.Entity>();
request.Mutation.Upsert.Add(entity);

var response = service.Datasets.BlindWrite(request, "***").Execute();
```

And the error is:

```
"invalid_grant", Description:"", Uri:""
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you manage to get a valid access token from `credential`? (Also note you also need the userinfo scope).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you'd need `userinfo.email` scope also:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

Also - make sure you've enabled the Cloud Datastore API (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094641/google-datastore-token-not-authorized/17219683#17219683)).